# Why does my UIScrollView squeeze my labels out of sight when it is connected correctly, but if I have an IB error, it works fine?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I made a test file for issues I'm having in a real project, and basically I have setup a UIScrollView in a brand new file in the default ViewController.

I have the following setup:

1. I set its constraints to 0 all around to the "Safe Area" (I've also
   done top level "View" - it made no difference).
2. I then have a single
   "Content View" with constraints set to 0 all around inside the
   ScrollView.
3. I have a collection of labels, buttons and UIViews (with height constraints) to give a constant string of constraints from top to bottom, with the last UIView having a constraint to the bottom of "Content View" >= 20.
4. I setup the "Content View" to have "Equal Widths" with the Safe Area (or main View)
5. Finally, I set "Content View" to have "Equal Heights" with the Safe Area (or main View) and it squeezes 3 of my Labels off the view entirely. If I remove the "Equal Heights" constraints, everything appears as it should, but IB complains that I "Need constraints for: Y position or height".

[image: Screenshot of IB showing full constraints on down the page with the only red being the lack of "Equal heights" for "Content View" to "Safe Area"]

Why is #5 causing these issues? Am I just supposed to set it up and accept that I have an IB error, even though the project runs fine and behaves as expected with this constraint missing? Or is there something I have missed?

Also, I'm using Xcode 9.3 and Swift4, so the latest and greatest.

Comment: Is all your labels’ contents are fixed? If so setting height constraint for them makes sense. If the labels’ contents are changing then you should rather set compression resistance and hugging priority to make the UI work properly. Also you can set the equal width and height of contentview to scrollview and not to safe area

Comment: Hi @KarthickRamesh, I have tried setting the equal width/height to the scrollView, that blew up even more spectacularly. But trying the compression resistance is a good idea, I might try playing with that a bit. The contents of the labels are flexible though, unknown how long they will be, so I'll have to see how it works out.

Comment: Did the compression resistence and hugging priority work out?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh It did not, I just tried both of them, separately and together, and it made it worse, no scrolling at all, and the labels squished off the display entirely. The only solution thus far is to delete the "Equal Heights" constraint, but that leaves IB with the error, but it runs perfectly?